# How we can achieve keyboard accessibility in website?

Tags: html, keyboard, accessibility

I am modifying my website for blind people.

How can I achieve keyboard functionality, i.e., using <kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate each and every link, menu, submenu etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you use HTML as intended (e.g., `a` for links, `button`/`input` for buttons, etc.), you don’t have to do anything. The elements that need to be focusable are focusable by default.

If you need to change the tabbing order, use the [`tabindex`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute) attribute.

If you have something that needs to be focusable, but you don’t/can’t use an appropriate element (e.g., you use `span` instead of `a` for a link), then you have to take care that this element can also be used/activated with a keyboard. [WAI-ARIA](https://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/aria) might become necessary to make your custom solution accessible.